# tableview sets label height to zero and the correct value, then opts to keep the zero making the label disappear

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

When I first load the tableview the two labels appear correctly in every cell. Then when I remove an item that has zero for the height of the bottom label, the item that replaces it in terms of position in the tableview then has a constraint conflict of zero and the correct height. The compiler always chooses zero, making my bottom label that's supposed to be seen, disappear. How do I get rid of this constraint conflict so my label stops disappearing in these scenarios?

Relevant code: In the view controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    guard let lineItem = orders[indexPath.section].lineItems?[indexPath.row] else { return 0 }
    let width = CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)
    guard let itemFont = UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Bold", size: 20),
        let modifierFont = UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Light", size: 20) else { return 0 }
    let heightForItemLabel = heightForView(text: "\(lineItem.name) (x\(lineItem.quantity))", font: itemFont, width: width)
    let text = generateModifierText(lineItem)
    let heightForModifierLabel = heightForView(text: text, font: modifierFont, width: width)
    return heightForItemLabel + heightForModifierLabel + 20
}

func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}

private func generateModifierText(_ menuItem: MenuItem) -> String {
    var text = ""
    guard let modifiers = menuItem.modifiers else { return "" }
    var optionNames = [String]()
    for modifier in modifiers {
        if !modifier.options.isEmpty {
            for options in modifier.options{
                if options.name.uppercased() != "NONE" {
                    optionNames.append(options.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for x in 0..<optionNames.count {
        if x != optionNames.count - 1 {
            text += "\(optionNames[x]), "
        } else {
            text += "\(optionNames[x])"
        }
    }
    return text
}
```

Then in the tableview cell:

```
func setup(_ lineItem: MenuItem) {

contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
// Item Label 
// itemLabel.backgroundColor = .white
itemLabel.text = "\(lineItem.name) (x\(lineItem.quantity))"
itemLabel.numberOfLines = 0
itemLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Bold", size: 20)
itemLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
modifiersLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

// Modifiers Label
// modifiersLabel.backgroundColor = .white
modifiersLabel.numberOfLines = 0
modifiersLabel.text = generateModifierText(lineItem)
modifiersLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Light", size: 20)
modifiersLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
modifiersLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
// Add Labels to Content View
contentView.addSubview(itemLabel)
contentView.addSubview(modifiersLabel)
// Get Devie UI Size
let width = CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)
// Get Text from function based on lines
let text = generateModifierText(lineItem)
// Set heights
heightForModifierLabel = heightForView(text: text, font: modifiersLabel.font, width: width)
heightForItemLabel = heightForView(text: "\(lineItem.name) (x\(lineItem.quantity))", font: itemLabel.font, width: width)

// Set Contraints
let modifiersLabelConstrains = [
    modifiersLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 50),
    modifiersLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
    modifiersLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightForModifierLabel),
    modifiersLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4),
    modifiersLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4),
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(modifiersLabelConstrains)

let itemLabelConstrains = [
    itemLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 50),
    itemLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
    itemLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightForItemLabel),
    itemLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130),
    itemLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 15),
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(itemLabelConstrains
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    modifiersLabel.text = ""
    heightForItemLabel = 0
    itemLabel.text = ""
    heightForModifierLabel = 0
}

func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}

private func generateModifierText(_ menuItem: MenuItem) -> String {
    var text = ""
    guard let modifiers = menuItem.modifiers else { return "" }
    var optionNames = [String]()
    for modifier in modifiers {
        if !modifier.options.isEmpty {
            for options in modifier.options{
                if options.name.uppercased() != "NONE" {
                    optionNames.append(options.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for x in 0..<optionNames.count {
        if x != optionNames.count - 1 {
            text += "\(optionNames[x]), "
        } else {
            text += "\(optionNames[x])"
        }
    }
    return text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution. But please use this code to update your question because your code is not understandable. I've changed the code In a way it makes more sense. Don't take it personal. We are here to help you. I've changed the color of each label. You just need to play with constrains and make sure you don't crash with another constrain that's already anchoring the same UI Object.

```
func setup(_ lineItem: MenuItem) {

    contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    // Item Label 
    // itemLabel.backgroundColor = .white
    itemLabel.text = "\(lineItem.name) (x\(lineItem.quantity))"
    itemLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    itemLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Bold", size: 20)
    itemLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    modifiersLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    // Modifiers Label
    // modifiersLabel.backgroundColor = .white
    modifiersLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    modifiersLabel.text = generateModifierText(lineItem)
    modifiersLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Light", size: 20)
    modifiersLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    modifiersLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    // Add Labels to Content View
    contentView.addSubview(itemLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(modifiersLabel)
    // Get Devie UI Size
    let width = CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)
    // Get Text from function based on lines
    let text = generateModifierText(lineItem)
    // Set heights
    heightForModifierLabel = heightForView(text: text, font: modifiersLabel.font, width: width)
    heightForItemLabel = heightForView(text: "\(lineItem.name) (x\(lineItem.quantity))", font: itemLabel.font, width: width)

    // Set Contrains
    let modifiersLabelConstrains = [
        modifiersLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 50),
        modifiersLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
        modifiersLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightForModifierLabel),
        modifiersLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4),
        modifiersLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4),
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(modifiersLabelConstrains)

    let itemLabelConstrains = [
        itemLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 50),
        itemLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
        itemLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightForItemLabel),
        itemLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130),
        itemLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 15),
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(itemLabelConstrains)


}
```

Comment: The problem is that when a tableview cell has no text for the bottom label and therefore sets that height to zero, when I delete the data for that cell and reload the tableview so data from the one below fills it in, the compiler says there's a conflict of a height of zero and the correct height. I have no idea how playing around with the code is going to change that. When I try coloring the labels, the bottom label disappears in this scenario, which is exactly what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: @michaeldebo can you show a mock or screenshot of what you are trying to achieve so I can help you here..

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do to fix the problem was not use a height constraint, but instead use a top and bottom constraint with the labels and make sure the number of lines equals zero. Then I needed to set the estimatedRowHeight and rowHeight to automaticDimensions. That's all.